# Is there a way to use dynamic variables in React or React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

GUEST_1 is a variable. I need to be able to change the number on the end dynamically and it would represent my variable. Is there any way to do this: currently I get GUEST_gestNumber not defined. There is different text that I get from this example GUEST_1 GUEST_2 GUEST_3

```
  const guest = (guestNumber) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{GUEST_guestNumber}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Comment: I recommend you do some basic programming tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
  const guest = (guestNumber) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{'GUEST_' + guestNumber}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

if not, your question is very unclear.

Comment: I tried this. All I get is GUEST_1 or GUEST_2.   I was hoping to get the text from it so for example GUEST_1 is a variable which should show Jerry and GUEST_2 should show Marry

Comment: then you can use the reference to the parent of the variable. something like `this['GUEST_1']` which would be in your case `this['GUEST_' + guestNumber]`